# Wordpress Plugin Scripts n Styles

Tags: wordpress

I am using this plugin for add the script to the page.when I add the script through plugin it gives to all page.How to add script to the single page using this plugin?

Comment: which plugin you are using??

Comment: Scripts n Styles Plugin

Comment: You can find the metabox of script n styles in the bottom of the each pages of your site. You can put the page specific script there.

Comment: I want to add through back end dynamically because script changes as requirement change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! you can add the script dynamically. navigate to the pages of your site, you can find the metabox in your page(Image is in below). if in any case you will not find the meta box you can check the **screen options** in the upper area of page select the checkbox of **Scripts n Styles** . Add the page specific code to that portion of the metabox. So, it will run on that specific page onl.

[image: script of page]